# Copying a lambda function with default parameters to a variable

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    auto f = [](int a = 3) {cout << a << endl; };
    f(2); // OK
    f();  // OK

    auto g = f;
    g(2); // OK
    g();  // OK

    function<void(int)> h = f;
    h(2); // OK
    h();  // Error! How to make this work?

    return 0;
}
```

How can I declare `h` to behave the same as `f` and `g`?

Comment: I don't think `std::function` has any default parameter support.

Comment: @MikeCAT I know that :) What is the correct way if I want to fully specify the type, if there is any?

Comment: `decltype(f)` gives you the type ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`std::function` has one fixed signature.  This was a design choice, not a hard requirement.  Writing a pseudo `std::function` that supports multiple signatures isn't hard:

```
template<class...Sigs>
struct functions;

template<>
struct functions<> {
  functions()=default;
  functions(functions const&)=default;
  functions(functions&&)=default;
  functions& operator=(functions const&)=default;
  functions& operator=(functions&&)=default;
private:
  struct never_t {private:never_t(){};};
public:
  void operator()(never_t)const =delete;

  template<class F,
    std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<std::decay_t<F>, functions>{}, int>* =nullptr
  >
  functions(F&&) {}
};

template<class S0, class...Sigs>
struct functions<S0, Sigs...>:
  std::function<S0>,
  functions<Sigs...>
{
  functions()=default;
  functions(functions const&)=default;
  functions(functions&&)=default;
  functions& operator=(functions const&)=default;
  functions& operator=(functions&&)=default;
  using std::function<S0>::operator();
  using functions<Sigs...>::operator();
  template<class F,
    std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<std::decay_t<F>, functions>{}, int>* =nullptr
  >
  functions(F&& f):
    std::function<S0>(f),
    functions<Sigs...>(std::forward<F>(f))
  {}
};
```

use:

```
auto f = [](int a = 3) {std::cout << a << std::endl; };

functions<void(int), void()> fs = f;
fs();
fs(3);
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/574313c182a1d25e).

This will create a separate copy of your lambda per overload.  It is even possible to have different lambdas for different overloads with careful casting.

You can write one that doesn't do this, but it would basically require reimplementing `std::function` with a fancier internal state.

A more advanced version of the above would avoid using linear inheritance, as that results in O(n^2) code and O(n) recursive template depth on the number of signatures.  A balanced binary tree inheritance drops that down to O(n lg n) code generated and O(lg n) depth.

The industrial strength version would store the passed in lambda once, use small object optimization, have a manual pseudo-vtable that used a binary inheritance strategy to dispatch the function call, and store dispatched-to function pointers in said pseudo-vtable.  It would take O(# signatures)*sizeof(function pointer) space in a per-class (not per-instance) basis, and use about as much per-instance overhead as `std::function` would.

But that is a bit much for a SO post, no?

[start of it](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/121fb04069de1eab)

Comment: did you just write this answers under 10mins or you copied it from your C++ snippets?

Comment: @BryanChen wrote it.  Compiled first time, which was the surprising part.  If I used a pre-written snippet, I'd hope I'd avoid that inefficient linear inheritance!  I have done things like this before, with poly-lambdas that don't use type erasure, but I don't think I've done a poly-`std::function`.

Comment: @Yakk Very interesting solution!

Answer (score 2):

I like the nice solution proposed by @Yakk.

That said, you can do something similar by avoiding the `std::function`s and using a proxy function for the lambda, variadic templates and `std::forward`, as it follows:

```
#include<functional>
#include<utility>
#include<iostream>

template<typename... Args>
void f(Args&&... args) {
    auto g = [](int a = 3) { std::cout << a << std::endl; };
    g(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
};

int main() {
    f(2);
    f();
}
```

Put the above ideas in a *functor* and you'll have a function-like object that does almost the same.

It has the problem that parameters are not strictly verified.
Anyway, it will fail at compile time if misused.